There is a linker error while trying to use SPI drivers in Nuttx
Iv've tried to compile custom app with SPI and got an error.
While I'm trying to use standard drivers in the NUTTx RTOS, it causes a linker error
LD: nuttx
arm-none-eabi-ld: nttx/nuttx/staging/libapps.a(CustomHello.cxx.nttx.apps.CustomApps.CustomHello_1.o): in function `etx_spi_accel_task(int, char**)':
nttx/apps/CustomApps/CustomHello/CustomHello.cxx:170:(.text._ZL18etx_spi_accel_taskiPPc+0x46): undefined reference to `spi_transfer(spi_dev_s*, spi_sequence_s*)'

I included files in, but can't get an access for the linker to compiled files (objects files were created)
It's a file listing
include <nuttx/config.h>

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <nuttx/i2c/i2c_master.h>
#include <nuttx/spi/spi.h>
#include <nuttx/spi/spi_transfer.h>

static int etx_spi_accel_task(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int ret = 0;
 static uint8_t tx_boofer[8] ;
 static uint8_t rx_boofer[8] ;
printf("ETX_spi_ACCEL: Task Starting\n");

fd_spi = open( ETX_SPI_DRIVER_PATH, O_RDWR);
  if( fd_spi < 0 )
  {
    printf("ETX_spi_ACCEL:ERROR - Failed to open %s: %d\n",
                                                   ETX_SPI_DRIVER_PATH, errno);
    ret = -1;
  }

//spi_register
    struct spi_trans_s mytrans;
    mytrans.delay = 0;
    mytrans.nwords = 4;
    mytrans.txbuffer = tx_boofer;
    mytrans.rxbuffer = rx_boofer;
    struct spi_sequence_s myseq;
    myseq.ntrans = 4;
    myseq.trans  = &mytrans;
    //ret = spidev_transfer(fd_spi, &myseq);
    spi2->ops->exchange()
  ret = spi_transfer (spi2, &myseq);
  // ssi_transfer(fd_spi,tx_boofer,rx_boofer,4);

  close(fd_spi);
  printf("ETX_spi_ACCEL: Task finishing\n");
  return EXIT_FAILURE;

}

It's a makefile listing
include $(APPDIR)/Make.defs

#Custom Hello built-in application info

PROGNAME = $(CONFIG_CUSTOM_APPS_CUSTOM_HELLO_PROGNAME)
PRIORITY = $(CONFIG_CUSTOM_APPS_CUSTOM_HELLO_PRIORITY)
STACKSIZE = $(CONFIG_CUSTOM_APPS_CUSTOM_HELLO_STACKSIZE)
MODULE = $(CONFIG_CUSTOM_APPS_CUSTOM_HELLO)

#Custom Hello
MAINSRC = CustomHello.cxx

include $(APPDIR)/Application.mk

